# How to generate a latent variable from a set of different kinds of variables with R?

Tags: r

For a `n` number of observations, I want to generate a latent variable (unobserved), I can assume or not that this variable has a specific distribution or not, from a set of other variables that proxy this latent variable. For my specific case, I want to generate latent ability, from a set of variables that proxy ability (observed ability). One variable is discrete, and exhibit normality, another is binary but very skewed, and the last one is an ordered categorical variable. This looks like my data, and I would like to estimate a response for each observation.

```
set.seed(123877)
# number of units
n <- 1000L

# age
age <- sample(rnorm(n, 25, 10))

# cum laude 
hon <- sample(0L:1L, n, TRUE, prob = c(.9, .1) )

# prestige of university
pres <- factor(sample(1L:25L, n, TRUE), labels = 25L:1L, ordered = T)

dat <- data.frame(id=1L:n, age, hon, pres)
```

Comment: Are you asking for simulation advice? It seems like your question is more of a statistical one rather than a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. [stats.se] is the right place to ask for statistical help. It seems odd to reverse engineer a latent variable; it would seem to make more sense to generate that variable first, and then generate your proxies as functions of that latent variable value.

Comment: I'm not asking for a simulation, maybe my question is more suitable for cross-validated, but also, maybe there are some packages in R to do this. For instance, I just discovered the 'ltm' package.

Comment: @MrFlick, I found a solution, do you think I should post it, or just delete the question because it is not useful for the community?

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, feel free to post it as an answer below to close out the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using the `ltm` package, here is the code:

```
set.seed(123877)
u.latent <- vector()
class(u.latent) <- 'try-error'

library('ltm')
while (class(u.latent)=='try-error') {
# numer of units
n <- 1000L

# age
age <- round(rnorm(n, 25, 10))

# cum laude 
hon <- sample(0L:1L, n, TRUE, prob = c(.9, .1) )

# prestige of university
pres <- sample(1L:10L, n, TRUE)

# pres <-factor(pres, levels = 1L:25L, ordered = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(age, hon, pres)

# latent variable  
u.latent <- try(gpcm(dat))  
}
```

We can test if the model fits the data:

```
GoF.gpcm(u.latent)
#H0 the model fits the data
#Ha: the model does not fit the data
```

The estimates of the latent variables are straight forward:

```
u.estimates <-factor.scores(u.latent)
hist(u.estimates$score.dat$z1)
```